# Random permuted blocks - Number of unique blocks

Tags: combinatorics

When using random permuted blocks to produce a randomisation list for treatment groups in a clinical trial. I know that the formula for the number of unique blocks (assuming equal allocation to each groups) is

$\frac{L!}{(M!)^N} $, where L= Block length, N= Number of treatment groups and M=L/N.

How would I got about generalising this to the case where the ratio isn't 1:1? This is because I wish to work out the number of unique blocks when there is 3 treatment groups with an allocation ratio 2:1:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients). For the case when one group is size $2M$ and the other two are size $M$, you'd have

$$\frac{L!}{(2M)!(M!)^2}\text{ possible orderings}$$